# Eclipse and CDT Binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using OpenCV with Eclipse and CDT but when I try to run, I get the error "Binary not found".I build the project but i get the same error.

I search here and I found two things: Properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Binary Parsers and I select PE Windows Parser.

Another thing that I do is put cmake agaisnt make.

But I have the same problem.

Anyone knows how I can avoid this error?.

I am working in Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to build a project try this.

1. Open your project files
2. Write your code
3. Save your project from **File** "**Save all**" or **just ctrl+shift+S**
4. Then build your code from **Project** " **Build all**" or **just ctrl+B**

After this step your Binary files must be created then you can run your project